# Solr. When indexing custom json, many fields of the same name are stored in one field

Tags: json, indexing, solr

I am trying to create an index from a json file using Solr 8.11.
Here is the content of my json file:

```
{
    "dict": "TEST En-En",
    "index_language": "En",
    "contents_language": "En",
    "lang": "En-En",
    "type": "explanatory",
    "words_count": "55236",
    "cards": [
        {
            "title": "hood",
            "title_index": "hood",
            "text": "<div class=m-l-15>definition</div> ",
            "text_index": "definition"
        },
        {
            "title": "'s Gravenhage",
            "title_index": "'s Gravenhage",
            "text": "<div class=m-l-15>definition</div> ",
            "text_index": "definition"
        },
        {
            "title": "'tween",
            "title_index": "'tween",
            "text": "<div class=m-l-15>definition</div> ",
            "text_index": "definition"
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect to receive the following:

```
{
    "dict": "TEST En-En",
    "index_language": "En",
    "contents_language": "En",
    "lang": "En-En",
    "type": "explanatory",
    "words_count": 55236,
    "title": "hood",
    "text": "<div class=m-l-15>definition</div> ",
},
{
    "dict": "TEST En-En",
    "index_language": "En",
    "contents_language": "En",
    "lang": "En-En",
    "type": "explanatory",
    "words_count": 55236,
    "title": "'s Gravenhage",
    "text": "<div class=m-l-15>definition</div> ",
},
{
    "dict": "TEST En-En",
    "index_language": "En",
    "contents_language": "En",
    "lang": "En-En",
    "type": "explanatory",
    "words_count": 55236,
    "title": "'tween",
    "text": "<div class=m-l-15>definition</div> ",
}
```

But I get this:

```
{
    "dict": "TEST En-En",
    "index_language": "En",
    "contents_language": "En",
    "lang": "En-En",
    "type": "explanatory",
    "words_count": 55236,
    "title": [
        "'hood",
        "'s Gravenhage",
        "'tween"
    ],
    "text": [
        "<div class=m-l-15>definition</div> ",
        "<div class=m-l-15>definition</div> ",
        "<div class=m-l-15>definition</div> "
    ]
}
```

That is, the **title** field from all documents is stored in one multi-valued **title** field.
Here is the schema:

```
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="dict" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="index_language" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="contents_language" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="lang" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="type" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="words_count" type="tint"/>
  <field name="text" type="text_general"/>
  <field name="title" type="text_general"/>
  <field name="text_index" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="title_index" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

This is the request:

```
path=/update/json/docs params={?split=/cards
&commitWithin=1000
&f=dict:/dict
&f=index_language:/index_language
&f=contents_language:/contents_language
&f=lang:/lang
&f=type:/type
&f=words_count:/words_count
&f=title:/cards/title
&f=title_index:/cards/title_index
&f=text:/cards/text
&f=text_index:/cards/text_index
+-H+'Content-type:application/json'
&overwrite=true
&wt=json}
```

According to the [documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html), I should get what I expect.
Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You haven't included the request you're making; since there really seems to be something wrong with that (`-H ..` which is a curl parameter has been included in the request, as has `?` in front of split, and I'm not sure if the other parameters should be presented like that?) Are you sure you're not just sending the query string verbatim as one long, escaped string?

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks you are right. Sign `?` was really redundant. When I removed it, I was able to get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an additional `?` in front of the `split` parameter, effectively making it not work - since it gets a parameter named `?split` and not `split`. Remove the additional `?` and it should work.